# With filepicker.io, is there a way to get the original file path?

Tags: filepicker.io

I am using filepicker.io and specially computer as main service.

I would like to get the original file path of a file uploaded through the API.
For example, if I upload a file located at `/my/path/in/my/computer/file.zip`, I will get in the `FPFile` object the filepicker.io URL but not the original file path.

Is there a way to get it ?

PS: I have tried to retrieve the stat of the file too without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to browser security limitations, the real local path of the file is never exposed to the javascript application. For more information, see http://davidwalsh.name/fakepath